# A warning when debugging a parallel processing in MPI?

Tags: debugging, mpi, visual-studio-debugging, visual-c++-2010-express

I have codes below :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "mpi.h"
#define NRA 512    /* number of rows in matrix A */
#define NCA 512   /* number of columns in matrix A */
#define NCB 512         /* number of columns in matrix B */
#define MASTER 0      /* taskid of first task */
#define FROM_MASTER 1  /* setting a message type */
#define FROM_WORKER 2  /* setting a message type */

MPI_Status status;

double a[NRA][NCA],   /* matrix A to be multiplied */
     b[NCA][NCB],       /* matrix B to be multiplied */
     c[NRA][NCB];      /* result matrix C */

main(int argc, char **argv)
{
int numtasks,   /* number of tasks in partition */
  taskid,       /* a task identifier */
  numworkers,   /* number of worker tasks */
  source,       /* task id of message source */
  dest,        /* task id of message destination */
  nbytes,         /* number of bytes in message */
  mtype,          /* message type */
  intsize,   /* size of an integer in bytes */
  dbsize,       /* size of a double float in bytes */
  rows,                       /* rows of matrix A sent to each worker */
  averow, extra, offset,      /* used to determine rows sent to each worker */
  i, j, k,   /* misc */
  count;
double t1,t2;

intsize = sizeof(int);
dbsize = sizeof(double);

MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &taskid);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numtasks);
numworkers = numtasks-1;

//printf("   size of matrix A = %d by %d\n",NRA,NCA);
//printf("   size of matrix B = %d by %d\n",NRA,NCB);
/*---------------------------- master ----------------------------*/
if (taskid == MASTER) {
printf("Number of worker tasks = %d\n",numworkers);
for (i=0; i<NRA; i++)
  for (j=0; j<NCA; j++)
    a[i][j]= i+j;
for (i=0; i<NCA; i++)
  for (j=0; j<NCB; j++)
    b[i][j]= i*j;

t1 = MPI_Wtime();

/* send matrix data to the worker tasks */
averow = NRA/numworkers;
extra = NRA%numworkers;
offset = 0;
mtype = FROM_MASTER;
for (dest=1; dest<=numworkers; dest++) { 
  rows = (dest <= extra) ? averow+1 : averow;  
  //printf("   Sending %d rows to task %d\n",rows,dest);
  MPI_Send(&offset, 1, MPI_INT, dest, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  MPI_Send(&rows, 1, MPI_INT, dest, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  count = rows*NCA;
  MPI_Send(&a[offset][0], count, MPI_DOUBLE, dest, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  count = NCA*NCB;
  MPI_Send(&b, count, MPI_DOUBLE, dest, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

  offset = offset + rows;
  }

/* wait for results from all worker tasks */
mtype = FROM_WORKER;
for (i=1; i<=numworkers; i++) { 
  source = i;
  MPI_Recv(&offset, 1, MPI_INT, source, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
  MPI_Recv(&rows, 1, MPI_INT, source, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
  count = rows*NCB;
  MPI_Recv(&c[offset][0], count, MPI_DOUBLE, source, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD,
             &status);

  }

#ifdef PRINT
printf("Here is the result matrix\n");
for (i=0; i<NRA; i++) {
  printf("\n");
  for (j=0; j<NCB; j++)
    printf("%6.2f   ", c[i][j]);
  }
printf ("\n");
#endif

t2 = MPI_Wtime();


fprintf(stdout,"Time = %.6f\n\n",
       t2-t1);

}  /* end of master section */

/*---------------------------- worker (slave)----------------------------*/
if (taskid > MASTER) {
mtype = FROM_MASTER;
source = MASTER;
#ifdef PRINT
printf ("Master =%d, mtype=%d\n", source, mtype);
#endif
MPI_Recv(&offset, 1, MPI_INT, source, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
#ifdef PRINT
printf ("offset =%d\n", offset);
#endif
MPI_Recv(&rows, 1, MPI_INT, source, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
#ifdef PRINT
printf ("row =%d\n", rows);
#endif
count = rows*NCA;
MPI_Recv(&a, count, MPI_DOUBLE, source, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
#ifdef PRINT
printf ("a[0][0] =%e\n", a[0][0]);
#endif
count = NCA*NCB;
MPI_Recv(&b, count, MPI_DOUBLE, source, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
#ifdef PRINT
printf ("b=\n");
#endif
for (k=0; k<NCB; k++)
  for (i=0; i<rows; i++) {
    c[i][k] = 0.0;
    for (j=0; j<NCA; j++)
      c[i][k] = c[i][k] + a[i][j] * b[j][k];
    }

//mtype = FROM_WORKER;
#ifdef PRINT
printf ("after computer\n");
#endif
//MPI_Send(&offset, 1, MPI_INT, MASTER, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
MPI_Send(&offset, 1, MPI_INT, MASTER, FROM_WORKER, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
//MPI_Send(&rows, 1, MPI_INT, MASTER, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
MPI_Send(&rows, 1, MPI_INT, MASTER, FROM_WORKER, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
//MPI_Send(&c, rows*NCB, MPI_DOUBLE, MASTER, mtype, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
MPI_Send(&c, rows*NCB, MPI_DOUBLE, MASTER, FROM_WORKER, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
#ifdef PRINT
printf ("after send\n");
#endif
}  /* end of worker */

MPI_Finalize();
} /* end of main */
```

The codes are matrix multiplication using MPI. When i try to debug it using visual studio 2010 express : it's display a warning [image: warning]

I want to ask, where was the problem during debugging the code? Does anyone can help me?

Comment: In which line you got this error?

Comment: `averow = NRA/numworkers;`

oh, i remember. is it because i try to add MPI_Wtime() then appear this error? Because when i delete it, the error is in line `mtype = FROM_MASTER;`

Comment: numworkers=numtask-1;  if you use only one process "numworkers" must be zero and this can cause above error. I don't know that, visual studio how handle with processes in debug. Are you tried to run your code?

Comment: I tried to run it, it's only appear `Number of worker tasks : 0` then i must define the numtask first?

Comment: "numtasks" is defined here: MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numtasks); When you run your code with "mpiexec" you declare it with the number of process.

Comment: yes, i declare it. But appear another error. Fatal error in MPI_Send: invalid rank, error stack ... job aborted: rank: node : exit code[: error message] 0: sinta-PC: 1: process 0 exited without calling finalize. (??)

Comment: MPI ranks range from `0` to `numprocs-1` where `numprocs` is what you get from `MPI_Comm_size`. Your loop runs from 1 up to and **including** numprocs which is one rank past the valid upper bound. Change `dest<=numworkers` to `dest < numworkers`.

Comment: hai `Hristo Iliev` i did your suggestion, when i debug it, the warning was same. but when i run it, appear error `rank: node : exit code[: error message]`  `0: sinta-PC: -1073741676: process 0 exited without calling finalize` why is the error warning different?

Answer (score 0):

The error is at this line:

```
averow = NRA/numworkers;
```

numworkers is 0, presumably because you haven't configured Visual Studio to launch the MPI job with more processes. It's pretty fiddly to get it to do the right thing here, especially when debugging.

Make sure the [MPI Cluster Debugger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee441265.aspx) is installed correctly - this is the most likely culprit.